# Insert Twitter Data from Java to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, insert

I want to insert twitter data from java to mySQL. these my code:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conne.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO kun(ID,name,statusLocation,text,source)"                       
                            + "VALUES('"                                 
                            + "','" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                            + "','" + user.getLocation()
                            + "','" + status.getText()
                            + "','" + status.getSource()
                            + "')");
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.setString(1,"'");
```

But the issue is tweet with single quote (') cannot inserted. Otherwise is inserted.

It shows this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Thanks for reply before

Comment: I think it's a little different. because I got the data from twitter which means I have to use such status.getText(), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work because of the following reasons:

1. You are trying to insert values into your query using `stmt.setString(1,"'");`, but you have no spaceholders in the query. That is the reason for the Exception with the text `(1 > number of parameters, which is 0)`. This has nothing to do with the single quote.
2. You call `stmt.executeUpdate();` before you call `stmt.setString(1,"'");`. You have to set the query parameters before you execute the query.
3. Your query is wrong. You specify 5 columns, but only give values for 4 columns (no value for the `ID` column). This might work though if the ID column is set to AUTO_INCREMENT in your database schema.

Change your code to this:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conne.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO kun(name,statusLocation,text,source) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, status.getUser().getScreenName());
stmt.setString(2, user.getLocation());
stmt.setString(3, status.getText());
stmt.setString(4, status.getSource());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: 1. I knew, I have tried many ways, but it still cannot work. I propose to escape from single quote

Comment: 2. I just tried to switch, but the result is still same. anw, thanks for replies

Comment: This has nothing to do with escaping any quotes. The ``PreparedStatement`` escapes all necessary characters by itself when you use the ``?`` placeholders and fill the with the ``setString`` methods.

Comment: Wow! It works! This is what I am looking for almost a day. Thank you very much f1sh! I know I have to use PreparedStatement but I don't know how to use. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Accept it as an answer to close it!